# A simple steganography

Tags: probability

1. I have a text of 2522 letters (X).
2. I hypothesize, on grounds external to X, that a given non-contiguous sequence of 11 letters (Y) will occur within a given string of 133 letters (Z) in X--from letters 1971 to 2103, if that's relevant.
3. Y does turn up within Z, in a string of 130 letters, i.e., short of Z's beginning by 1 letter and short of Z's end by 2 letters. However,
4. Y turns up 8 other times in Z in strings of more or less the same number of letters as Y (as per natural probability due to limited alphabet).
5. What is the chance against 3. occurring if Y is entered into X randomly, assuming that the same sequence will turn up in at least 8 strings of more or less the same number of letters as Y? Great? Very great? Extremely great? Astronomically great?

Background: Some scholars maintain that in precisely the line of an ancient Latin poetic text that reveals the author's homeland the author's name is encrypted (as a simple steganography). Others maintain that the conjunction of the letters of the name is coincidental. More weight might be added to the former position if it were possible show that the chance against the conjunction of those letters occurring coincidentally in that position is significantly great.

The problem would have been of the kind solved easily by means of the binomial coefficient equation, which I can handle, but in the present problem the fact that the letters involved are not contiguous but separated by other letters puts the solution beyond my ability.